# Interpreting where values reside on a Linux 32-bit process address space

Tags: c, memory, memory-address

I am trying to get to grips with the Linux process address space and saw this question as a good opportunity to get to grips with things. Could anybody out there advise as to what section of the process address space the following reside?

The code that implements strcpy - I believe this to be in th DLL section.

The variable p1 - I believe this to be on the heap as it id dynamically allocated.

The location pointed to be *p1.

The location pointed to by *p2.

The string literal "I am a string".

Thanks in advance!

```
int main()
{

    char *p1 = NULL;
    void *p2 = (void *)0xDDDDDDDD;
    p1 = malloc(100);
    strcpy(p1, "I am a string");

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Where what resides? The program, its variables, or the allocated memory? You can find where the memory was allocated with `printf(%p\n", (void*)p1)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variables and calls in a C program and its corresponding location in the Linux process address space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54145441/variables-and-calls-in-a-c-program-and-its-corresponding-location-in-the-linux-p)

Answer (score 0):

The virtual memory layout of a Linux process looks like this:

[image: diagram of process layout]

(Source: [Wikipedia, Dougct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Program_memory_layout.pdf).)

The process is divided into different memory segments, depending on how you allocate the memory. Wikipedia has [a good explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) of what each is for.

Let's go through the program, line by line.

Lines 1-2: declare 2 pointers, which are kept on the stack.

Line 3: Allocate 100 bytes on the heap. Make p1 point to it. In other word: p1 is a pointer (located on the stack) to a piece of memory (located on the heap.)

Line 4: Copy a string literal (stored in the text section) to a piece of memory (located on the heap.)

Line 5: Return. This de-allocates the space for the pointers, but does not de-allocate what they point to. The region of memory pointed to by p2 is not freed, so there is a memory leak. (Although, the program is ending, so it doesn't matter here.)

> The code that implements strcpy - I believe this to be in the DLL section.

The short answer is, "text section."

The complete answer is, "it depends on your compiler settings."

Let's say you link your program statically:

```
$ gcc -static test.c
$ ./a.out & pmap $!
0000000000400000      4K r---- a.out
0000000000401000    492K r-x-- a.out
000000000047c000    140K r---- a.out
00000000004a0000     24K rw--- a.out
00000000004a6000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
00000000007df000    140K rw---   [ anon ]
00007ffc6031b000    132K rw---   [ stack ]
00007ffc60358000      8K r----   [ anon ]
00007ffc6035a000      8K r-x--   [ anon ]
ffffffffff600000      4K r-x--   [ anon ]
```

The second line, `0000000000401000    492K r-x-- a.out` is the text section. Notice it's pretty big for our 5 line program. That's because we put the libraries we're using into our text section.

On the other hand, you could link it dynamically:

```
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out & pmap $!
[1] 5637
5637:   ./a.out
0000555943977000      4K r---- a.out
0000555943978000      4K r-x-- a.out
0000555943979000      4K r---- a.out
000055594397a000      4K r---- a.out
000055594397b000      4K rw--- a.out
00005559442ca000    132K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f3af067b000    136K r---- libc-2.27.so
00007f3af069d000   1304K r-x-- libc-2.27.so
00007f3af07e3000    300K r---- libc-2.27.so
00007f3af082e000     16K r---- libc-2.27.so
00007f3af0832000      8K rw--- libc-2.27.so
00007f3af0834000     16K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f3af0838000      8K rw---   [ anon ]
00007f3af085e000      4K r---- ld-2.27.so
00007f3af085f000    120K r-x-- ld-2.27.so
00007f3af087d000     32K r---- ld-2.27.so
00007f3af0885000      4K r---- ld-2.27.so
00007f3af0886000      4K rw--- ld-2.27.so
00007f3af0887000      4K rw---   [ anon ]
00007fff10f99000    132K rw---   [ stack ]
00007fff10fc2000      8K r----   [ anon ]
00007fff10fc4000      8K r-x--   [ anon ]
ffffffffff600000      4K r-x--   [ anon ]
```

Notice two things: Our text section (`0000555943978000      4K r-x-- a.out`) is now tiny. Also, we can see that libc has been loaded into its own section of memory. (The diagram I showed above glosses over this detail - a more complete diagram is here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466443/do-memory-mapping-segment-and-heap-grow-until-they-meet-each-other)